# Ошибка компиляции

Tags: node.js, javascript

Пишу на haxe, версия 3.1.3, в flashdevelop. Компиляция в JavaScript, подключаю библиотеку HaxeFoundation / hxnodejs для работы с Node.js. Поначалу ругался на недостающие классы (прим. haxe.EitherType и др.), скачал HaxeFoundation / haxe и скопировал недостающие файлы. Теперь ругается на строки со следующим содержанием:

```
var Readable : ReadableEvent<Void->Void> = "readable";
var Data : ReadableEvent<haxe.EitherType<Buffer,String>->Void> = "data";
и тд.
```

Пишет следующую ошибку: **Type hints on enum abstract fields are not allowed**
В чём возможна проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогли решить данную проблему. Нужно скачать development-ветку из репозитория и собрать. Или скачать последнюю сборку с [builds.haxe.org](http://builds.haxe.org) (что намного проще)
Спасибо большое Dan Korostelev из спб.